# CCMotionStreak after CCsprite move from one to another point in ios?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

hello friend i want to CCMotionStreak effect after Sprite move.i am implement for CCMotionStreak effect on Touch Event.but now i implement on Sprite path after it move.

[image]

My Code As below That only Event

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]))
    {

    self.touchEnabled = YES;
    CCMotionStreak *torpedoStreak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:1.7f minSeg:10 width:10 color:ccWHITE textureFilename:@"Button1.png"];
    [torpedoStreak setPosition:torpedoOne.position];
    [self addChild:torpedoStreak z:2];
    }
 }


-(void)createMotionStreak:(NSInteger)touchHash
{
    streak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:1.7f minSeg:10 width:10 color:ccWHITE textureFilename:@"Button1.png"];
    [self addChild:streak z:5 tag:touchHash];
}

-(void)removeMotionStreak:(NSInteger)touchHash
{
    [self removeChildByTag:touchHash cleanup:YES];
}

-(CCMotionStreak*)getMotionStreak:(NSInteger)touchHash
{
    CCNode* node = [self getChildByTag:touchHash];
    if(![node isKindOfClass:[CCMotionStreak class]]) {
        [self createMotionStreak:touchHash];
    }
    return (CCMotionStreak*)node;
}

-(void) addMotionStreakPoint:(CGPoint)point on:(NSInteger)touchHash
{
    CCMotionStreak* streak = [self getMotionStreak:touchHash];

    streak.position = point;

    //[streak.ribbon addPointAt:point width:32];
}

-(CGPoint)locationFromTouch:(UITouch*)touch
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    return [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSEnumerator* enumerator = [touches objectEnumerator];
    UITouch* oneTouch = nil;
    while (oneTouch = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        [self addMotionStreakPoint:[self locationFromTouch:oneTouch] on:oneTouch.hash];
    }
}

-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{


    NSEnumerator* enumerator = [touches objectEnumerator];
    UITouch* oneTouch = nil;
    while (oneTouch = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        [self removeMotionStreak:oneTouch.hash];
    }

}
```